# How to Avoid Redirection in my Browser

Tags: browser, http-redirect

There area few sites which get redirected to some other links when i visit them.

e.g. when i am logged in through facebook from my browser and if i simultaneously open an another tab in which i open any site (say Nextag.com) which supports FbLogin feature, then the site gets automatically redirected to the login page and i am automatically logged in.

How can i Force websites from getting redirected, and alternatively how can i force them to get redirected to the page i want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I can .
Which platform you use , I dont know . But I try to tell it in php .
First download the php sdk from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Then create a folder lethe , and create a subfolder "lib" in your directory.
To lib folder copy and paste the src folder in sdk .

Then create a file in lethe .

```
 <? require 'lib/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'yourAppId',
  'secret' => 'YourAppSecret',
));
    $userIns = $facebook->getUser();
    if(!$userIns) { header("location:http://mywebsite.com/login.php?ref=Open")} 

   else {
// Here The Code When you realise that user use your api and can open the user session
//@ your site , maybe bring him name and surname from graph.api or via sql query from your //db
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

If you can success to reach the facebook cookie (you can find it in facebook developers)
then with php or other languages , you can find out if
facebook session open or close , then you can redirect . The other way is search
"OPENID".

Comment: can you elaborate more on the first one?